# constexpr функция вместо define "функции"

Tags: c++, resharper

```
#define MethodHandler( Object, Method ) createMethodEventHandler( Object, &Method )
```

ReSharper выдаёт предупреждение "function-like macro used; consider a constexpr template function", что значит: используйте constexpr функцию, вместо define.
но при этом ReSharper не говорит как это сделать.

как заменить define на constexpr?

createMethodEventHandler объявлен так:

```
template<class TObject, class ...TParams>
EventHandler<TParams...>& createMethodEventHandler(TObject& object, void(TObject::* method)(TParams...))
```

Comment: Какой-то бесполезный макрос, вроде как единственное, что он делает - это добавление `&` перед `Method`. Зачем его использовать вместо `createMethodEventHandler`? Может там было `&Object::Method`?

Comment: @VTT, для улучшения читаемости

Comment: передать аргументу функции и обьект и его функцию_член и получить ссыльку на другой обьект тип которого зависит от переданного метода?.. Не представляю как эта функция должна быть полезна. Неужели у вас есть столько же внешных обьектов, сколько методов у класса? Или я неправильно понел?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , я использовал систему событий.

Comment: Мы не видим полный пример кода. Вдруг у вас `EventHandler` имеет constexp конструктор? Или ReSharper просто рекомендует вам воздержаться от макросов.

Comment: @MrBin, нет, не имеет. ReSharper просто рекомендует воздержаться от макросов

Comment: Я думаю, что можно сделать constexpr конструктор для `EventHandler`, при условии, что он будет несложным по логике и содержать только указатель на функцию.

Comment: @MrBin, спасибо, изучу этот вопрос